# Mid-20th century sci-fi short story. Trying to remember name and author

Tags: story-identification

I'm trying to think of the name of a story I read a long time ago (maybe by Keith Laumer? Frederik Pohl?) It involved a guy trying to gain access to a storeroom containing the greatest treasures of the universe. He had to get past a robot/computer guardian who posed riddles, and he figured out that the only correct answer would be one that made no sense at all. This was after he watched someone else with access to a backpack version of a "Watson"-like computer, which gave him all the correct answers, try and fail (resulting in the man's execution).

> The catch was, after the guy gave the correct nonsense answer, he was admitted to the treasure room, where he took what he wanted. Upon exiting, the robot asked him why he had taken those particular items. He replied, "Because I want them!" (or words to that effect). And then, because his answer made sense, the robot killed him.

I've looked up lists of Pohl's and Laumer's stories, but nothing stands out in the titles.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, that's it. "The Sixth Palace": I found it [on Amazon](http://www.amazon.com/Dark-Star-Collected-Stories-Silverberg-ebook/dp/B004JKMU46/ref=sr_1_20?s=digital-text&ie=UTF8&qid=1392513116&sr=1-20&keywords=robert+silverberg+kindle+books) in a Kindle edition. Instant gratification!